# UML with subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private String grade;
    private int[] test;
    private int NUM_TESTS;

    public Student(){
        name="Un";
        id=0;
        grade="Un";
        test=new int[0];
        NUM_TESTS=5;
    }

    public Student(String x, long z) {
        name=x;
        id=z;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name=n;
    }
    public void setID(long i) {
        id=i;
    }
    public void setGrade(String g) {
        grade=g;
    }
    /*public void setTestScore(int t,int s) {
        test=t;
        test=s;
    }

    public int getTestScore(int) {
        return test;
    }*/
    public int getNumTests() {
        return NUM_TESTS;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public long getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getTestScore()+getNumTests()+getName()+getID()+getGrade();
    }
    /*public void calculateResult() {
        int sum=0;
        for (int t:test)sum+=t;
        double average= 1.0t*sum/5;*/

    }
}
```

Here is my code I have spaced out the places where I am having the issues. I am writing a Student subclass with subclasses undergrad and postgrad. 
[Here is the UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDQR.png)
I don't understand how to correctly implement testScore if it is not one of the variables? Nevermind the calculate result I'll fix that myself. I am also unsure if my constructors are accurate. All the students do five exams that's a constant

Comment: What is exactly `setTestScore()`want to do? Be specific. Secondly, don't name your variables like `String n`, or `int t`, with just one character, because we cannot understand the context. Imagine if your method instead of `getTestScore()` was called `s()`. What in hell would that method mean!

Comment: it's a mutator method ,

Comment: @Skemelio we are asked to allow them to input their exam results, but would that be done in the mutator method , in cases with subclasses? This is why I am confused as there is no variable for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `setTestScore(int t, int s)`... I do recommend to use carefully chosen names (identifiers). For example if you just rename the parameters to: `setTestScore(int testNumber, int score)` you can be more familiar what should you inplement.
- `test = new int[0];`isn't what you want. You want `test = new int[NUM_TESTS]`
- Try to reconsider method `setTestScore(int testNumber, int score)` 
      first parameter is actually the index in the array of `test` and the second is the value.
- So, your method should be something like this:

  ```
  public void setTestScore(int testNumber, int score) {
      test[testNumber] = score;
  }
  ```

I just gave you some guidance for your own implementation...

Comment: Thank's I will keep that in mind, however I don't understand why getTestScore then only has one int?

Comment: `getScore(int testNumber)` should return `test[testNumber]`. That is the int _score_ value for the test in the array

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It seems that `Student` class should be `abstract`. because each student is `UnderGraduate` or `PostGraduate`.

Secondly, you should `extend` the child classes from `Student` class.

I hope the below code be helpful:

```
abstract class Student {

    private String name;
    private long id;
    private String grade;
    private int[] test;
    private final int NUM_TESTS = 5;

    public Student(){
        name = "UN";
        id = 0;
        grade = "UN";
        test = new int[NUM_TESTS];
    }

    public Student(String name, long id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //TODO: write your desire toString method
        return getNUM_TESTS()+getName()+getId()+getGrade();
    }

    abstract void claculateResult();

    public int getTestScore(int testNumber){
        if(testNumber >= NUM_TESTS)
        return 0;

        return test[testNumber];
    }

    public void setTestScore(int testNumber, int score){
        if(testNumber >= NUM_TESTS)
            return;

        test[testNumber] = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int[] getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(int[] test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public int getNUM_TESTS() {
        return NUM_TESTS;
    }
}
```

and the `UnderGraduate` class would be:

```
public class UnderGraduate extends Student{

    public UnderGraduate(){

    }

    public UnderGraduate(String name, long id){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    void claculateResult() {
        //TODO: DO whatever you want
    }
}
```

remember that the `PostGraduate` class is same as `UnderGraduate`.

Comment: Thank you, and if I put public instead of abstract would that make a difference?

Comment: Because the uml isn't an abstract class

Comment: The only difference is in the instantiation of objects. you have no implementation for `calculateResult`. It makes you implement `calculateClass` while you are creating a new object of `Student` type.